# TS | Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<SecurityMode, boolean>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, interface

I Have a `DTO`, which I am using in order to map through one of its keys

**THE DTO and the SecurityMode enum:**

```
enum SecurityMode {
  mode1 = 'mode1’,
  mode2 = 'mode2’,
  mode3 = 'mode3’
}

export default SecurityMode;
```

```
import SecurityMode from 'shared/common/enums/SecurityMode';

export default interface IAuthUser {
  security: Record<SecurityMode, boolean>;
}
```

**THE ERROR:**

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<SecurityMode, boolean>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record<SecurityMode, boolean>'.ts(7053)
```

**Here is the part of the Code, the error is presenting:**

```
{user && user.security && user.security[securityKey] && ( // The error is on user.security[securityKey]
          <Fragment>
            <span">{securityKey}</span>
          </Fragment>
        )}
```

So, how do I remove this error? What is his problem?

I tried changing the security to:

```
security: Record<{[key: string]: SecurityMode, boolean}>
```

but the Record Generic only takes 2 arguments, and when I am putting them into a var, I get that I am using them as values. PLEASE HELP..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  user.security[securityKey as SecurityMode]
```

The problem is not the type of `user.security` but the type of `securityKey` as that can be any string, also one that isn't part of `user.security`. As `undefined` / `false` have the same meaning here (I assume), it is safe to cast the string to the string literal union type, then the error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my first error. But now a new one appeared. `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Record<SecurityMode, boolean>'.` Any idea?

Comment: Same line? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, same line. This one: `user.security[securityKey as SecurityMode]`

Comment: You seem to use a module alias (`shared/common`), are you sure that `SecurityModule` is properly resolved?

Comment: Yeah SecurityMode is being resolved. As I am accessing it in the same Page elsewhere..

Comment: Seems like if I change the default export to named export the problem is resolved. But why? Weird.

Comment: Thats really weird, I never had that behaviour ... Anyways, glad to help :)